# Error removing an HDD from a RAID1 BTRFS array

Tags: raid, btrfs

I setup a btrfs filesystem on 3 disks with RAID 1. Somehow, a small portion (2GiB) got used as RAID0. At the time, no amount of running `btrfs balance -dconvert raid1 -mconvert raid1` would change it so I left it as is.

Lately `/dev/sda` is starting to show SMART errors and general issues. So I added 2 other disks to the btrfs array, and then proceded to run `btrfs device delete`. All of the data was correctly moved out of `sda` *except* 1 GiB, and the delete fails with this message:

```
> # ./btrfs device delete /dev/sda /storage 
ERROR: error removing the device '/dev/sda' - No space left on device
```

It seems there is a small part of `sda` that still has a RAID 0 partition, and that small part cannot be deleted. This is a completely uninformed assumption! It's just that the 1 GiB space remaining on disk seems suspicious.

I don't know what files are there, and at this point I really don't care. I would like to nuke that 1 GiB partition so I can remove `/dev/sda` and get my array working correctly.

I tried to run a `balance -dconvert` again, but the command starts moving my data back *into* sda and I don't trust the disk to die on me while writing that much data.

Any tips or suggestions are apreciated! Thank you,

My system information:

```
$ uname -a
Linux nerd-server 3.13.0-48-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 12 11:16:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Using the latest btrfs-tools:

```
$ ./btrfs --version
btrfs-progs v4.1.2
```

`/dev/sda` stubbornly keeps 1 GiB of data. Running `btrfs device delete` just errors out quickly.

```
$ ./btrfs fi show
Label: none  uuid: 5e63e5b5-48bb-442e-a79c-1c71a22de476
Total devices 5 FS bytes used 3.86TiB
devid    1 size 2.73TiB used 1.00GiB path /dev/sda
devid    2 size 2.73TiB used 1.97TiB path /dev/sdd
devid    3 size 2.73TiB used 1.81TiB path /dev/sdc
devid    4 size 2.73TiB used 1.97TiB path /dev/sde
devid    5 size 2.73TiB used 1.97TiB path /dev/sdf
btrfs-progs v4.1.2
```

There seems to be a a RAID 0 section with very little data in it.

```
$ ./btrfs fi df /storage
Data, RAID1: total=3.85TiB, used=3.85TiB
Data, RAID0: total=2.00GiB, used=1.54GiB
System, RAID1: total=32.00MiB, used=744.00KiB
Metadata, RAID1: total=6.00GiB, used=4.64GiB
```

This shows that the RAID 0 section is only on `/dev/sda` and `/dev/sdd`. I don't care if I lose the data there, I just want to get `/dev/sda` out of my array! The disk is empty except for the 1 GiB partition, so the "no space left on device" error is confusing for me.

```
$ ./btrfs device usage /storage
/dev/sda, ID: 1
   Device size:             2.73TiB
   Data,RAID0:              1.00GiB
   Unallocated:             2.73TiB

/dev/sdc, ID: 3
   Device size:             2.73TiB
   Data,RAID1:              1.81TiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          5.00GiB
   System,RAID1:           32.00MiB
   Unallocated:           939.49GiB

/dev/sdd, ID: 2
   Device size:             2.73TiB
   Data,RAID0:              1.00GiB
   Data,RAID1:              1.96TiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          6.00GiB
   System,RAID1:           32.00MiB
   Unallocated:           775.49GiB

/dev/sde, ID: 4
   Device size:             2.73TiB
   Data,RAID1:              1.97TiB
   Unallocated:           774.52GiB

/dev/sdf, ID: 5
   Device size:             2.73TiB
   Data,RAID1:              1.97TiB
   Metadata,RAID1:          1.00GiB
   Unallocated:           775.52GiB
```

Answer (score 1):

im guessing that you are using 14.04 lts. so 1st thing should be upgrading the kernel to 3.19 and try again. there is still heavy develpment on btrfs and though we are facing strange bugs from time to time. there are similar bugs reportet for raid 5/6 that will maybe fixed in k4.1.

s.